# Grub error prevents booting Windows 8 from DVD

Tags: windows-8, grubrescue

Half a year ago (end support XP), I installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows XP on my computer to maintain internet access. Now that I have purchased Windows 8, I tried to install this instead of Windows XP. However, trying to boot from the DVD, grub gave me an error. I dont remember the exact error, but it made sense to run boot repair disk to fix grub. After I did this (http://paste.ubuntu.com/9398619/), I still couldnt reach the DVD so I decided to uninstall Ubuntu and XP using OS installer. (paste.ubuntu.com/9398802/)

However, I still can't reach the windows DVD, even if I choose this option as my number one boot option or if I boot directly to it using the boot menu. Grub intervenes with this message:

error no such device: 998a5ba3-... 
Entering rescue mode

I tried to repair grub again, but without success ((http://paste.ubuntu.com/9400269/) 
All solutions to similar problems posted here include repairing grub or removing it using a windows DVD, but as stated above both options don't work for me.

Can anyone please help me out here? Thanks in advance.
I'd be happy to provide more info if needed.

Comment: Why not boot from dvd?

Comment: I wish I could boot from DVD, but it fails to do so. It looks like my computer is just ignoring the DVD-drive since it boots to grub. I'm going to look into that now

Answer (score 1):

For booting from CD/DVD you don't need a bootloader such a grub. You usually use the BIOS or EFI. Insert the Windows DVD and reboot your computer and press the one of these keys: F1, F2, F8, F10 or DEL. Then you get to the BIOS and EFI and you can configure your BIOS to boot from DVD or directly select you DVD-Drive to boot. After this you should reach the Windows 8 installer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZJ5i3eYgKA